# Rubymotion MapKit Path Overlay

Tags: ios, mapkit, rubymotion

Does anyone know of any code examples that display paths on a MKMapView using RubyMotion?

I've found some useful examples that display a point or pin but none that display a path.

Thanks

Comment: For the record I was able to draw a line on the map like this:

Answer (score 1):

For the record I was able to draw a line on the map like this. Hopefully this is useful to someone as I could find no examples drawing lines on a map using RubyMotion:

```
arr = [CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(49.7414435, -123.08), CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(50.7414435, -123.0)]
ptr = Pointer.new(CLLocationCoordinate2D.type, arr.length)
ptr[0] = arr[0]
ptr[1] = arr[1]
pl = MKPolyline.polylineWithCoordinates(ptr, count:2)
view.addOverlay(pl)
```

With the help of this discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubymotion/F5CH780lu7c

Comment: What is the complete code you use to show on map? I tried your code and it does not draw on map unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon this (which was very helpful), you also need to create a `viewForOverlay` method, like so:

```
def mapView(map_view, viewForOverlay:overlay)
  if overlay.class == MKPolyline
    overlayView = MKPolylineView.alloc.initWithPolyline(overlay)
    overlayView.strokeColor = UIColor.systemRedColor
    overlayView.lineWidth = 2
    overlayView
  end
end
```